# How to print these lines letter by letter?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I want this output need to wait for one element's text to finish being typed before starting the next one? How can I do it?

```js
//This is a promise function for waiting
function wait(ms = 0) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
// this function will get a random number between minimum to maximum valye
function getRandomBetween(min = 20, max = 150, randomNumber = Math.random()) {
  return Math.floor(randomNumber * (max - min) + min);
}

//this is my draw callback function for draw every letter of the word
async function draw(el) {
  const text = el.textContent;
  let soFar = '';
  //for loop every letter of the word
  for (const letter of text) {
    soFar += letter;
    el.textContent = soFar;
    // wait for some amount of time
    const {
      typeMin,
      typeMax
    } = el.dataset;
    const amountOfTimeToWait = getRandomBetween(typeMin, typeMax);
    await wait(amountOfTimeToWait);
  }
}
//here I select every element and run draw function for each element
document.querySelectorAll('[data-type]').forEach(draw);
```

```html
<h2 data-type data-type-min="100" data-type-max="300">
  This text will be typed
</h2>
<h2 data-type data-type-min="20" data-type-max="80">
  This text will be typed faster
</h2>
<h2 data-type>This text will be typed the default speed</h2>
```

Comment: [some examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+await+one+after+another+site%3Astackoverflow.com+-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are synchronously calling draw for every elements. So they all immediately start to draw. You need to call it for the first and wait for it to be done before calling for the next.

```js
//This is a promise function for waiting
function wait(ms = 0) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
// this function will get a random number between minimum to maximum valye
function getRandomBetween(min = 20, max = 150, randomNumber = Math.random()) {
  return Math.floor(randomNumber * (max - min) + min);
}

// this is my draw callback function for draw every letter of the word
async function draw(el, content) {
  const text = content;
  let soFar = '';
  // for loop every letter of the word
  for (const letter of text) {
    soFar += letter;
    el.textContent = soFar;
    // wait for some amount of time
    const {
      typeMin,
      typeMax
    } = el.dataset;
    const amountOfTimeToWait = getRandomBetween(typeMin, typeMax);
    await wait(amountOfTimeToWait);
  }
}

async function drawAll(elNodeList) {
  // Make sure the element list is an actual array.
  const elList = Array.from(elNodeList);
  // Save the content of all elements because we need to clear them all.
  const elContentList = elList.map(el => el.textContent);
  for(let i = 0; i < elList.length; i++) {
    elList[i].innerHTML = '';
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < elList.length; i++) {
    // Await for draw to be done before moving the next loop iteration.
    await draw(elList[i], elContentList[i]);
  }
}

//here I select every element and run draw function for each element
drawAll(document.querySelectorAll('[data-type]'));
```

```html
<h2 data-type data-type-min="100" data-type-max="300">
  This text will be typed
</h2>
<h2 data-type data-type-min="20" data-type-max="80">
  This text will be typed faster
</h2>
<h2 data-type>This text will be typed the default speed</h2>
```